# Smart pointer deleter and "using" keyword with a name "pointer"

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Sometimes ago I saw a code like this:

```
void* Create()
{
    int* t{new int{10}};
    return t;
}

class Deleter
{
    //uncomment in order to compile
    //using pointer = void*;
public:
    void operator()(void* t)
    {
        delete t;
    }
};

unique_ptr<int, Deleter> ptr{Create()};
```

It doesn't compiles. With VS2013 it says:

> error: C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list'
>   to 'std::unique_ptr' No constructor could take the source
>   type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

But if I uncomment line `using pointer = void*;` it works! Also if I change a name of alias to something different than `pointer` I get the same error. So it seems that having a `using` directive with exact name `pointer` is crucial. But why? I couldn't find any explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `unique_ptr` declared with `T=int`. However, [constructors in `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) take not `T*`, but `pointer` argument instead.

This `pointer` type defined as

```
std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer if that type exists, otherwise T*
```

And when you don't provide `Deleter::pointer` it ends up as `int*`, and of course can't be initialized from `void*` (from `Create`).

Answer (score 2):

> `[C++11: 20.7.1.2/3]` If the type `remove_reference<D>::type::pointer` exists, then `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer` shall be a synonym for `remove_reference<D>::type::pointer`. Otherwise `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer` shall be a synonym for `T*`. The type `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer` shall satisfy the requirements of *NullablePointer* (17.6.3.3).

It's required here because you have no `operator()(int*)` — you are "hacking" around that to allow `operator()(void*)` to be used instead by making the deleter pretend it's a deleter for `void*`.

Whether your deleter as a whole remains strictly valid even when it compiles, I wouldn't like to say.